# How can I change the color of several words in the TextField Widget?

Tags: flutter

Im trying to do chat mentions and I need to some how change the color of full name that mentioned in the TextField before send the message.

How can I do that?

Comment: Till now this feature is missing In flutter. Only One custom Library is there which can be used to define different styles to text in textField.  https://pub.dev/packages/zefyr.

Comment: Yes you are right @Vicky Salunkhe. After some researches Im also found only Zefyr but it's not what I need.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hope i'm not too late :)
I had the same issue and couldn't find any implementation in the main flutter package or any third party packages, so i hacked a little packaage and uploaded it. 
it's an extension of the text editing controller that you can supply with a map of Regex patterns and corresponding Text style.

> https://pub.dev/packages/rich_text_controller
>
> https://github.com/micwaziz/rich_text_controller

Comment: Thank you, great job! Sorry for late answer. I'm accepting your answer, seems it will work)). in the past I was looking something like this. Sorry but I cannot test it, I'm on another project now, but I beleive this will work))

Answer (score 1):

In case someone stumbles across this question (like I did) but requires the textfield to render tap-able links, then here's one way to do it (simplified from our final implementation for better clarity). It's inspired by the RichTextController, but with the definitive focus to allow for taps on the links.

Regarding the regular expression: We tried using linkify, but despite trying all options, it tended to modify the links - which messed up the user input.

```
import 'package:flutter/gestures.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class LinkedTextEditingController extends TextEditingController {
  final RegExp linkRegexp;
  final TextStyle linkStyle;
  final Function(String match) onTap;

  static RegExp _defaultRegExp =
      RegExp(r'((?:(https?:\/\/)?)(www\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,5}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*))', caseSensitive: false, dotAll: true);

  static void _defaultOnLaunch(String url) async {
    final re = RegExp('^https?://');
    final fullUrl = re.hasMatch(url) ? url : 'http://$url';
    if (await canLaunch(fullUrl)) {
      await launch(fullUrl);
    }
  }

  LinkedTextEditingController({
    String text,
    RegExp regexp,
    this.linkStyle,
    this.onTap = _defaultOnLaunch,
  })  : linkRegexp = regexp ?? _defaultRegExp,
        super(text: text);

  LinkedTextEditingController.fromValue(
    TextEditingValue value, {
    RegExp regexp,
    this.linkStyle,
    this.onTap = _defaultOnLaunch,
  })  : linkRegexp = regexp ?? _defaultRegExp,
        assert(
          value == null || !value.composing.isValid ||     value.isComposingRangeValid,
          'New TextEditingValue $value has an invalid non-empty composing range '
          '${value.composing}. It is recommended to use a valid composing range, '
          'even for readonly text fields',
        ),
        super.fromValue(value ?? TextEditingValue.empty);

  @override
  TextSpan buildTextSpan({TextStyle style, bool withComposing}) {
    List<TextSpan> children = [];

    text.splitMapJoin(
      linkRegexp,
      onMatch: (Match match) {
        children.add(
          TextSpan(
            text: match[0],
            style: linkStyle,
            recognizer: onTap == null ? null : TapGestureRecognizer()
              ..onTap = () => onTap(match[0]),
          ),
        );
        return null;
      },
      onNonMatch: (String span) {
        children.add(TextSpan(text: span, style: style));
        return span;
      },
    );

    return TextSpan(style: style, children: children);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

as Durdu suggested, you can use RichText to achieve different color text. Just need to put multiple TextSpan with different color using TextStyle. Sample as below

```
Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20.0, right: 20.0, top: 10.0, bottom: 10.0),
            child: RichText(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              text: TextSpan(
                children: [
                  TextSpan(
                    text: 'By clicking sign up, you have read and agreed to our ',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                  ),
                  TextSpan(
                    text: 'Terms & Conditions',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                    recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                      ..onTap = () {
                        print('Tapped on hyperlink');
                      },
                  ),
                  TextSpan(
                    text: '.',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

[image]

Hope this clears and solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @Steve Chan, but I need to change words with different styles while typing. Its should be something like RichTextEditor Widget, but there is no such thing yet.

Answer (score -3):

If you just want to change the color or font for the text in the textfield:

```
Text("Hello", 
     style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900))
```

If you want to use multiple styles you should check, you should check [RichText](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html).

> The RichText widget displays text that uses multiple different styles.

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Hello ',
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900)),
    children: <TextSpan>[
      TextSpan(text: 'bold', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
      TextSpan(text: ' world!'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: OP wants to provide different color to string text in `TextField`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need to change the color of several words within the TextField Widget not in Text Widget. Its about chat mentions, when you mentioning someone in the TextField, his name should be in another color.